# Reading bigrams in a proper way

Tags: c++

I'm developing a program that should read bigrams from a text file and classify them in a 2D matrix. It reads them in this way for example, if the word in the file is "Hello", it'd read it as: "He", "el", "ll", "lo" and then classify them in the matrix according how much times those bigrams are found all over the text file.

The function I'm writing for that purpose uses a stream (as it receives a file as argument) and I wanted to use the read() function to read 2 characters (to get the bigram), store them in an array and then classify them. The problem is, with that function, I won't be able to read bigrams the way I exposed above, it'll just read them as "He" "ll" "o " (the last one is not going to be valid).

This is the code for the actual function. Any suggestions to achieve what I'm asking?

```
bool BigramCounter::calculateBigramsFrecuency(const char* nfile){
ifstream finput;
bool result = true;
char bigram[3];

finput.open(nfile);

if(finput){
    while(!finput.eof()){
        finput.read(bigram, 2);

        for(int i=0; i<this->getSize(); i++){
            for(int j=0; j<this->getSize(); j++){
                if(_validCharacters[i] == bigram[0] && _validCharacters[j] == bigram[1]){
                    _bigrams[i][j]++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(!finput){
        cerr << "Reading error\n";
        result = false;
    }

    finput.close();
}

else{
    cerr << "Opening error\n";
    result = false;
}

return result;
```

}

Comment: Read **one** character at a time; remove the first one from the previous bigram, and add the new character at the end of the bigram.

Comment: Gratuitous advice: `ifstream fentrada(nfichero);` will create and open the input file. Don't separate the two. Don't call `fentrada.close()`; the `ifstream` destructor will do that. `while (!fentrada.eof())` will run the loop an extra time: `eof()` tells you that the previous read attempt failed. Use `while (fentrada.read(bigram, 2))`; that will break the loop when there is no more input. Don't bother with `if(fentrada)`; if the open failed, `fentrada.read(bigram, 2)` will fail, and the code won't enter the loop. `if (!fentrada)` will always be true: the loop exited because the input failed.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Hello Jesper, I've just translated it into English. Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: @PeteBecker Thanks for the advices, Peter. So for reading one char at a time, I should use the function get() instead?